# re-engineering database using oracle sql developer data modeler does not include synonyms

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-schema, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I am trying to re-engineer a DB schema using oracle sql developer data modeler version 3.0.04 using this as a reference:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldevdm/r40/mod1_dm_v4/mod1_dm_v4.html
The schema is huge and all the tables are in the "synonyms". Even though I choose the synonyms (regardless of the number of them) they are not visible in the final diagram. If I choose from "tables" they are displayed in the final diagram.

Does anybody know how to fix this? Should I use a different version? I have to do this process using sql developer only, but is there an easier tool?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a sample DDL you could share here or offline?

Comment: You should treat synonyms as distinct objects just like tables. Select everything you want reverse engineered. Are you selecting _both synonyms and tables_ simultaneously?

Comment: So your schema doesn't have tables, it only has synonyms to tables in another schema? And you want those synonyms treated as tables in the design, and to see them in  your diagram as tables with the relationships?

Comment: I did treat synonyms as distinct objects and selected what I wanted (just synonyms, there are tables, but they are just not desired to be reengineered)

Comment: Are they private or public synonyms? Sounds like private from where you're seeing them, but just checking...

Answer (score 0):

You can't import only the synonyms. You need to import the underlying tables that those synonyms point to.

If you have SELECT privs on the tables, you'll be able to import them to your relational model in Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler.